# I want to merge the value in column A before Delimeter to B

Tags: excel

I want to merge the value in column A before Delimiter[image] to B such that for the column D I get the value of before delimiter[Name Sam] and for column E I get the value after delimiter [Address California]. Is there any formula for that ?

Comment: `=LEFT(A1, SEARCH("|",A1,1)-1)` and so on

Comment: Thanks @L.ScottJohnson  found full result using this =LEFT(A1, SEARCH("|",A1,1)-1) & " " & B1